# $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left(R\ln\frac{R+1}{R-1}\right)=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

I've seen this limit a lot lately while working with generalized integrals, but I can't really  seem to understand how you compute it. I know the limit is 2, but how do you find this limit?

I've noticed that if you generalize the limit to:

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left(R\ln\frac{R+a}{R-b}\right), \quad a,b\in \mathbb{R},$$ you get the sum a+b.

Comment: Have you tried anything, and where did you come across the question?  Generally, questions with relevant context and some idea of what has been tried get more replies here, see [How to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've come across it computing generalized integrals. Can't remember the first one I encountered but the one I'm working on right know has the primitive function evaluated in the following limits: $\left[x\ln{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}+\ln{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}\right]_2^\infty$. However I'm not really interested in the solution of this integral. It just happened to be what made me come across this for the second time. I'm interested in this limit only. Therefore I thought the context of how I got to this limit was irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\ln\frac{R+a}{R-b}=\ln\frac{1+a/R}{1-b/R}=\ln\left(1+\tfrac{a}{R}\right)-\ln\left(1-\tfrac{b}{R}\right)\in\tfrac{a+b}{R}+O\left(\tfrac{1}{R^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that

\begin{equation}
R\log \left(\frac{R+1}{R-1} \right) = \log \left[\left(1+\frac{2}{R-1} \right)^R \right] = \log \left[\left(1+\frac{2}{R-1} \right)^{R-1} \left(1+ \frac{2}{R-1} \right) \right]
\end{equation}

Now use the fact that $\log$ is a continuous function in $(0,\infty)$ and $e^k = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{k}{n})^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L_1=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)^x = \exp\left(\lim_{x\to \infty} x \left(\frac{2}{x-1}\right)\right)=e^2$$
So $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1/R$, then show that

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left(R\ln\frac{R+1}{R-1}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln (1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}.$$

Now use L'Hospital.

Comment: By $0+0$ did you mean $0^+$ (`0^+`)?

Comment: Yes "$0+0=0^+.$"